# I connect Twitter and Google, but then error: {"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

I use sparks with Codeigniter and want connect Social Platforms. Facebook works, but twitter and google not.

My error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error
>   fetching remote [https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token](https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access%5ftoken) [ status
>   401 ]   Invalid /
>   expired Token /oauth/access_token  '
>   in
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/OAuth.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/Request.php(504):
>   OAuth::remote('https://api.twi...', Array) #1
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/Request/Access.php(20):
>   OAuth_Request->execute(NULL) #2
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/Provider.php(214):
>   OAuth_Request_Access->execute() #3
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/application/controllers/auth.php(74):
>   OAuth_Provider->access_token(Object(OAuth_Consumer),
>   Object(OAuth_Token_Request)) #4 [internal function]:
>   Auth->oauth('twitter') #5
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 /home in
>   /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/OAuth.php
>   on line 87

What can i do my code for solution? Thank you.

Comment: The error message says your OAuth token has expired. Have you tried renewing it?

Comment: Thanks. But now my error change :D


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error fetching remote http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=72985339 [ status 403 ] {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}' in /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/OAuth.php:87 Stack trace: #0 /home/binotumv/public_html/beta/sparks/oauth/0.3.1/libraries/Request.php(504): OAuth::remote('http://api.twit...', Array) ...

Comment: That looks like you aren't using SSL. Ensure your URL starts with https.  Upgrade your OAuth library to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, you right. My server settings will change, Thanks a lot :)